# How to execute a php file in eclipse programmatically

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I have a plugin where I have contributed to options menu pop up. I am popping up a wizard to get user values on selecting the options menu. On getting these values I am creating a .php file. Now after the creation of this php file I want to execute it as well. The code for the creating the file is as follow

```
public void editDeploy(String root,String username,String password,String projectName){

    IWorkspaceRoot myWorkspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
     IProject myProject = myWorkspaceRoot.getProject(projectName);
       // open if necessary
       if (myProject.exists() && !myProject.isOpen())
        try {
            myProject.open(null);
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       IFile deploy=myProject.getFile("deploy.php");
       StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
       ...Some Code to append in String Builder
       String contents=sb.toString();
       InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes());
       try {
           System.out.println("Entered2");
        deploy.create(source, false, null);
        System.out.println("Done");
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So how can I execute the deploy.php file here?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a clean solution but i am able to achieve the task by

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K \"cd "+dirPath+" && php deploy.php\"");
```

where dirPath is the directory where deploy.php is. If there is a better way please let me know.

Comment: PHPExe* classes from PDT might me helpful: https://github.com/eclipse/pdt/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.php.debug.core/src/org/eclipse/php/internal/debug/core/PHPExeUtil.java